# Format UTC using datepipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to format the UTC datetime to 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'. I tried this using the datepipe. However it converts it to the localtime. How can I format UTC to the required format.

Stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxr43w

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Date pipe [accepts a timezone](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) check the docs

```html
<p>
  UTC: {{date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a":"+0000"}}
</p>
```

[Check this out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vztkre?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Alternatively you could use ‘UTC+0’, which I think it's self-explanatory

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution is to use the *short* parameter value set to `"UTC"`:

```
<p>
  UTC: {{date | date: 'short':'UTC'}}
</p>
```

Angular pipes cast dates to locale timezone unless you specify it: [angular -datepipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#format-examples)